# Need help in deploying custom model in AWS SageMaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

We're trying to deploy a custom optimizer model into SageMaker. Our model consists of a number of .py files distributed across the repo and some external lib dependencies like ortools. Input CSV files can be put into a S3 bucket. Output of our model is a pickle file which is based on Input CSV files (these will be different each time someone runs a job).

We would prefer not to use ECR but if there's no other way option then can we follow the link below in order to achieve what we're aiming for? This sagemaker endpoint is expected to be called from a stepfunction.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-inference-code.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd encourage you to check out the examples [here](https://github.com/RamVegiraju/SageMaker-Deployment/tree/master/AdvancedFunctionality/CustomInference) for BYOC deployment.
Would require more information particularly on the framework and model to suggest further.